# Replace "link" when migrate from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am in the process of migrating from the legacy FCM APIs to the HTTP v1 API. In the old API, I used the "link" field in the notification payload to deep link to a specific screen when the user clicks on the notification. However, I couldn't find a replacement for the "link" field in the new HTTP v1 API.

Here is an example of the old API request that includes the "link" field:

```
POST /fcm/send HTTP/2
Host: fcm.googleapis.com
content-type: application/json
authorization: key= ***
{
  "notification": {
    "title": "Notification Title",
    "body": "Notification Body",
    "link": "appName://screen"
  },
  "to": "device token"
}
```

In the new API, I have successfully migrated to the HTTP v1 API with the following request, However, I couldn't find a way to specify the deep link in the new API. The notification currently directs the user to the home screen instead of the desired specific screen:

```
POST /v1/projects/project-id/messages:send HTTP/2
Host: fcm.googleapis.com
user-agent: insomnia/2023.5.8
content-type: application/json
authorization: Bearer ***
{
  "message": {
    "token": "device token",
    "notification": {
      "title": "Notification Title ",
      "body": "Notification Body"
    }
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve deep linking in the new HTTP v1 API. Thank you.

I tried the following but does not work for me

```
POST /v1/projects/project-id/messages:send HTTP/2
Host: fcm.googleapis.com
user-agent: insomnia/2023.5.8
content-type: application/json
authorization: Bearer ***
{
  "message": {
    "token": "device token",
    "notification": {
      "title": "Notification Title ",
      "body": "Notification Body"
    },
    "data": {
      "link": "appName://screen"
    }
  }
}
```